# How to configure argparse to be like a comment central kind of cli

Tags: python, command-line-interface, argparse

I'd like to do something like:

```
my-cli.py todo1 --todo1-option1 --todo1-option2 ...


my-cli.py todo2 --todo2-option1 --todo2-option2 ...
```

In addition, I'm hoping to declare `--todo1-option1` is required if the command is `todo1` and it is invalid parameter if I specify parameters for different command (i.e. todo2)

I'm also looking to have different -h for different command (i.e. todo1 or todo2).

I'm sorry if my English is a little broken. I hope you get what I mean.

The way I understand some tutorials, the main python app is the action itself like for example:

```
cp -f file1 file2
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.  `argparse` can certainly handle your first two examples, but why do you have a `.js` extension?  Did you actually want to ask about Javascript?

Comment: Any trial that we can improve on it?

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks. I've corrected the .js to .py.  And as to whether it can be done, it's yes and no. I'm actually looking at being able to do `my-cli.py todo1 -h` and `my-cli.py todo2 -h` and the required parameter should only be tested based the first positional argument.

Comment: No.  You will have to validate the parameters after you process them.  `argparse` can't do complex logic.

Comment: @TimRoberts, ok, it just a flat set of rules then.  I saw some mutually exclusive options.  I'm just thinking that there's just some clever technique to achieve what I have in mind.  Nonetheless, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I thought there's some clever trick using the `add_mutually_exclusive_group` but the answer to my question is in fact the `subparsers`

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='commands')

# A todo1 command
todo1_parser = subparsers.add_parser(
    'todo1', help='List contents')
todo1_parser.add_argument(
    '--todo1-option1', action='store', required=True,
    help='Todo1 Option 1')
todo1_parser.add_argument(
    '--todo1-option2', action='store',
    help='Todo1 Option 2')


# A todo2 command
todo2_parser = subparsers.add_parser(
    'todo2', help='List contents')
todo2_parser.add_argument(
    '--todo2-option1', action='store', required=True,
    help='Todo2 Option 1')
todo2_parser.add_argument(
    '--todo2-option2', action='store',
    help='Todo2 Option 2')

print(parser.parse_args())
```

Test for list of commands:

```
     $ python test_argparse.py 

     python test_argparse.py usage: test_argparse.py [-h] {todo1,todo2} ...
     test_argparse.py: error: too few arguments
```

Test for Todo1 required parameters:

```
     $ python test_argparse.py todo1 

     usage: test_argparse.py todo1 [-h] --todo1-option1 TODO1_OPTION1 [--todo1-option2 TODO1_OPTION2]
     test_argparse.py todo1: error: the following arguments are required: --todo1-option1
```

Test for Todo1 required parameters:

```
     $python test_argparse.py todo2
     
     usage: test_argparse.py todo2 [-h] --todo2-option1 TODO2_OPTION1 [--todo2-option2 TODO2_OPTION2]
     test_argparse.py todo2: error: the following arguments are required: --todo2-option1
```

Test for Todo2 shouldn't be availble to Todo1:

```
     $python test_argparse.py todo1 --todo2-option1 aaa 
     usage: test_argparse.py [-h] {todo1,todo2} ... test_argparse.py: error:
     unrecognized arguments: --todo2-option1 aaa
```